# Structure misalignment solves itself after refreshing CSS values on inspector

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive

I don't really know how to phrase my problem. [My page](http://www.vigocontraelcancer.es/) is working fine and all, responsive included (resizing my PC browser). But when I open the page from a browser in an actual phone, the blue section with icons gets all messed up.

There's apparently nothing wrong with it on the code. The thing that is driving me mad is, and as soon as I change anything from the inspector, it corrects itself (but that's something my users aren't going to do). It doesn't matter whether I change the color of a random text or anything, it reacts correcting itself whenever I make a change in the CSS on the inspector.

Can anyone help me figure this out? I'm attaching a screenshot from my phone before and after changing CSS on the inspector:

[image: broken issue]

[image: broken issue]

Answer (score 1):

In which mobile did you try to show it?

I don't know if you solved it but i try to see your website from my smartphone and i show it correctly.

Comment: I'm seeing this bug in Chrome for Android (in a Aquaris M5). I've tried the same thing on Firefox, and it seems that it only happens on Chrome.

Comment: You can try to put in the css code of the object that display the image correctly, use the prefix -webkit-. Here you have a link that can help you: http://aprenderaprogramar.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=761:prefijos-css-de-navegador-chrome-firefox-iexplorer-opera-safari-webkit-moz-ms-o-ejemplos-cu01056d&catid=75:tutorial-basico-programador-web-css-desde-cero&Itemid=203

Comment: Here you have a link that applies @media only for chrome: https://gitlab.com/snippets/17238

Comment: Still no luck isolating the CSS with @media queries for Chrome :( I've also tried to emulate changes in console via javascript on load, but doesn't work either.

Comment: If you use media query, can you put here the media query css rule that you are using to show this icons in a mobile devices? If we see the code it's easiest to found an error. Thanks!